# Фильтрация по плохим словам

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Крайне редко можно наткнуться на [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468912/discord-py-client-get-user-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-none?noredirect=1#comment2629068_1468912) такой конфуз. Действительно, можно согласиться с автором ответа если просмотреть активность автора вопроса. Однако я считаю крайне не приемлемым использование таких слов и выражений.

Мне кажется отличная идея ввести список крайне неприличных выражений при наличии которых в тексте, этот текст нельзя будет опубликовать. К слову интересно пытались ли вводить такое?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле это цирк.

Comment: Что-то подобное вроде было......но, кажется, для комментариев.......для вопросов/ответов тоже есть фильтр, правда не по матерным словам, а по словам приветствия вроде.... мне кажется добавить туда списки с матерными вполне можно было бы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это крайне нелогично что слова которые  показывают доброжелательность фильтруются, а крайне плохие слова вполне способны протечь в ответы/вопросы.

Comment: У ресурса конкретная цель и конркетное позиционирование, поэтому всякий мусор, в т.ч. всякие приветствия, пожелания доброго дня и прочее из школьные эмоции - отсекалось..... про мат - точно не скажу было что-то или нет...но как правило такое быстро низвергается до последнего круга ада))

Comment: Мата на ресурсе достаточно мало, как мне кажется, а реагируют на него жёстко. Поэтому авто-фильтр может быть не особо востребован.

Comment: @Kromster Так или иначе добавить фильтр по мату не сложная задача, однако это может улучшить опыт многих людей.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Абсолютно согласен с тем, что информация не по существу несёт вред. Однако вы возможно не поняли, я имел ввиду что мат куда негативнее приветствия.

Comment: @DaYa ну это-то понятно)  но по этому момент уже написал  Kromster выше, ну и я это упомянул тоже........но добавить бы слова не помешало бы...... как это реализуется не знаю

Comment: В самом деле, ведь слово *причем* в данном контексте должно писаться **слитно**

Comment: "Так или иначе добавить фильтр по мату не сложная задача" — в общем случае, это сложная задача, требующая NLP решения (склонения, обход через замены символов и проч.). В случае простого списка возникают сложности с его поддержкой и проблемы с [false positives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordfilter#False_positives). Текущий механизм минуса + тревоги позволяет достаточно быстро удалять такие посты вручную (т.к. тревога на "невежливый или оскорбительный" имеет больший приоритет для модераторов, а также может ставить дополнительные минусы).

Comment: @tocic Выше я уже писал что это не решение проблемы,  ответ на скриншоте провисел достаточно давно, этого времени хватит чтоб сделать негативными впечатления от SO.

Comment: @avp Автор ответа уже показал себя 3мя словами ранее. Не считаю неправильное написание таких слов за что то серьёзное, т.к сам крайне неправильно пишу.

Comment: @tocic, а если еще добавить приставки и суффиксы, а также вспомнить, что середина некоторых вполне легальных слов совпадает с абсценной лексикой, то станет ясно, что проще отбросить ханжество и перейти к пропаганде истинной толерантности

Comment: А если какой то "чудик" решил освоить йоптаскрипт и задаст вопрос, выложив часть кода? При этом "чудик" сам он вежлив, но вот код...

Comment: @SwaD Куда большим преступлением против человечества будет задать вопрос с brainfuck, а йоптаскрипт я напомню, не совсем самостоятельный язык программирования и легко конвертируется в JS на официальном сайте йоптаскрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление фильтра может не помешать, однако ради таких крайне редких случаев, где недружелюбные вопросы и ответы так или иначе будут в скором времени удалены, это не сильно нужно. Можно полностью согласится с тем что приход к взаимопониманию между людьми решит большинство проблем.

Итог: Фильтр не является необходимостью так как такие случаи редки и недружелюбные сообщения будут удалены.